# Three.js: When and how often are attributes passed to GPU

Tags: three.js

I'm working on a WebGL scene in Three.js that uses custom shaders and am trying to optimize the rendering. To do so, I'm wanting to understand: When and how often is data passed into the GPU?

Does every vertex, uv, etc. that are passed as attributes or uniforms into the shaders need to be passed in each frame, or do these values get passed once and cached until the user sends new data for a given attribute or uniform key?

I'd be grateful for any help others can offer in describing the times when data is passed into the GPU in WebGL.

Comment: Ah, so does that mean in the following example, we pass *all of the buffers* (including the point buffer) to the GPU every frame, as we call `gl.uniformMatrix4fv` every frame? https://bl.ocks.org/duhaime/e22aa2a7dc1874ca4535c36e1930a590

Comment: @Rabbid76 I'm afraid I'm confused. Inside `render()` (which is called every frame) the example calls `setMatrixUniforms()`, which in turn calls `gl.uniformMatrix4fv()`, which led me to believe, given your comment, that we'd pass all the data to the GPU every frame, as we're calling `uniform*` inside the render call. Are you saying here we only pass data to the GPU once?

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for following up

Comment: uniform data is passed every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BufferGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/BufferGeometry) is very efficient because it sends attributes (such as UVs, normals, vertices, and indices) only *once* to the GPU when you declare the Mesh.

If you want to make changes to one of these attributes after it's been initiated, at a later frame, you must set its `.needsUpdate` property to true, and *then* it will be re-sent to the GPU. Otherwise, the initial values will remain in GPU cache undisturbed.

See: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/BufferAttribute.needsUpdate

Comment: do you know why people go crazy using instanced geometries and indexed geometries in that case? If the data just has to go to the GPU once, why spend so much time optimizing the geometry attributes?

Comment: Hmm... i don't understand what you mean. What do people go crazy about?

Comment: People spend lots of time optimizing things like the attribute data to be sent to a mesh--e.g. they use an instanced geometry, which reduces the number of attributes required to render a geometry. Is this kind of optimization useful for anything other than minimizing the amount of data to be passed to the GPU? To ask a more targeted version of the question: Will an instanced geometry be more performant once the data has arrived on the GPU than a non-instanced geometry, ceteris paribus?

Comment: It all depends on how many objects you'll render. For example, let's say you want 50 cubes, you could make 50 separate `BufferGeometry`s or just 1 `InstancedBufferGeometry` with an attribute of 50 "offsets" to declare their positions. The former will consume much more memory than the latter; in essence, 8 * 50 is much larger than 8 + 50. See this accepted answer for a more detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41880864/how-to-use-three-js-instancedbuffergeometry-instancedbufferattribute?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: so is the value of an InstancedBufferGeometry in the RAM savings? Or is there some kind of benefit that manifests each frame?

Comment: Could be both RAM and CPU benefits once your poly-count is high enough. Every `render()` has to make several JavaScript calls to the WebGL API, and if you have thousands of Meshes to render, the JavaScript will slow down the CPU, lowering your framerate. `InstancedBufferGeometry` will offload these slow JS calls to the graphics card, calculating via GLSL, thus relieving the CPU. You can notice the speed increase when you select "instanced" and a high geometry # in this example: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_instances_gpu.html

Comment: I don't think that stack overflow is the most appropriate format for this kind of Q&A. This almost invalidates the previous answer, if the conclusion is "people are going crazy". It's still a valid question of sorts, but the context where it comes from kinda skews it / taints it. I'm not sure what to suggest though. In the context of three it seems valid to ask how much does something occur which is happening under the hood, but then again there's the "what's the difference between an `attribute` and a `uniform` hidden here.

Comment: There may be something wrong with the accepted answer here, if it leads to more confusion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50077508/three-js-indexed-buffergeometry-vs-instancedbuffergeometry

Comment: This may be the more appropriate medium for this kind of discussion, i think a lot of these questions spilled out into the comments. https://discourse.threejs.org/ <- i'd discuss there then digest the answers here, because they are useful

Comment: @pailhead  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: "people are going crazy"

Comment: @Marquizzo Could rendering a BufferGeometry where each vertex is rendering primitive (ie. a cube) via Signed Distance Function be more performant solution than InstancedGeometry? Just wondering and would like to get your opinions on that.

Comment: @mtx I have no idea what your implementation or use-case might be, so I can't answer whether SDF is more performant than geometry instancing in your situation. But rendering instanced cubes is super cheap in the vertex shader, so you might be wasting your time trying to write custom SDFs when it's not really necessary.