# How to merge meshes with different colors and have only one draw call?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a lot of the same meshes. They have the same material, but with different colors. Is there a way i could merge their geometries in one bufferGeometry and set one material to it?

Yes, i can add all materials to material array, merge geometries to bufferGeometry, add index and create one Mesh. But in this way, i'll have as many draw calls as materials, but i need only one.

Comment: It sounds like you have a different problem than what you're asking. Are you saying you have several meshes of the same shape, but different colors? Why do you think you only need one draw call?

Comment: @TheJim01, hi, sorry, may be my bad english brought a misunderstanding. I have a lot of this meshes, and a big number of draw calls which makes my canvas lagging. As they all a pretty the same, i'm wondering if there is a way to make it with one draw call. As i need only to change colors, may be there is any trick?

Comment: You can try with vertex colors, i don't have any code at the moment and am trying to find out what's the user friendly way of doing this.

Comment: You can also try instancing. [This answer discusses the differences between basic geometry and instanced geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41880864/how-to-use-three-js-instancedbuffergeometry-instancedbufferattribute/43476114#43476114), and you can apply instanced attributes like how you would apply vertex colors.

Comment: instancing wont work if there are many different meshes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use vertex colors for this

```
const myMeshes = [...]

//first go through all the meshes, and tell them that they have another attibute
//in addition to whatever they already have 
myMeshes.forEach( mesh=>{
  const thisMeshColor = new THREE.Color().copy(mesh.material.color) //the color you want to distribute
  //expand the data to match the vertices
  mesh.colors = mesh.vertices.map(vert=>thisMeshColor)
}

//merge here

//apply this to material and it should "work" 
myMerges.material.vertexColors = THREE.VertexColors
```

somewhat pseudocode, not tested. THREE R92